# How to make match() work with date in excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having problem making the match() work in excel VBA. The code is:

```
x = Application.Match("Sep 2008", Range("F1:F1"), 0)
```

The value in cell F1 is 9/1/2008.

Even if I changed Sep 2008 to 9/1/2008, it still doesn't return any value.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: What if you changed "Sept 2008" to cdate("Sept 2008")

Comment: That doesn't return any value too. I added the line msgbox x but there is no output.

Comment: what if you change Range("F1:F1") to Format(Range("F1").Value, "mmm yyyy") so you are comparing string against string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your best bet is to use `.Find()`. This will **return a `range`** if found or `nothing` if not.

```
Set x = Range("F1:F1").Find(CDate("Sept 2008"), , , xlWhole)
```

If you wanted the **column number**:

```
x = Range("F1:F1").Find(CDate("Sept 2008"), , , xlWhole).Column
```

**With capture of not found**

```
Sub test()

    Dim y As Date, x As Variant, c As Long
    y = CDate("Sep 2008")
    Set x = Range("1:1").Find(y, , , xlWhole)
    If Not x Is Nothing Then
        c = x.Column '<~~found
    Else
        Exit Sub 'not found
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I need to find the column location and paste the relevant data into the cell. It's a matrix.

Comment: if you wanted the column number use `x = Range("F1:F1").Find(CDate("Sept 2008"), , , xlWhole).Column`

Comment: `x = Range("1:1").Find(CDate("Sept 2008"), , , xlWhole).Column` would find it in the first row

Comment: @TingPing I've added a sub. this will also check for a not found date in row 1...

Comment: @glh You may like to have a look at [this](http://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/match-vs-find-vs-variant-array-vba-performance-shootout/) site

Answer (score 21):

The reason why `Even if I changed Sep 2008 to 9/1/2008, it still doesn't return any value.`

Is because when there is a Date in excel, Excel automatically converts that date to a numeric value, What you really want to search for is:

`39692`

This number is the number of days between `9/1/2008` and excel default of 1/1/1900

every date in excel is stored with a value like this. So the easiest way to handle this would be to convert what you see as a date to what excel sees as a date using `CDate()`.

This by itself will give you an unuseful error that vba can't get the property.

That is because the Lookup_value can be a value (number, text, or logical value) or a cell reference to a number, text, or logical value. Not a date so simply convert the now date value to a number to search for the matching number in the list using `CLng()`

Give this a shot it will also be much faster then using the Find alternative:

```
x = WorksheetFunction.Match(CLng(CDate("Sep 2008")), Range("F1:F1"), 0)
```

This should give you the result expected

To handle when no match is found try this Sub:

```
Sub MatchDate()
Dim myvalue As Double
Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp)

On Error GoTo NotFound
myvalue = WorksheetFunction.Match(CLng(CDate("Sep 2008")), Range("F1:F" & LastRow), 0)
MsgBox (myvalue)
End

NotFound:
MsgBox ("No Match Was Found")
End

End:
End Sub
```

Comment: @glh Nothing personal I promise, I just wanted to make sure they understood WHY I was given them another option when it seemed they already had a working solution.

Answer (score 4):

Bottom line:

- **use `WorksheetFunction.Match(CDbl(date), range, 0)`**
- **Alternatively, use a `Date` cell's `Value2` property** (which will also be a `Double`) **instead of `Value` for the search key.**

`CLng` suggested in other answers would discard the time part of the `date`.

The same problem exists for the `Currency` data type but you can't use `CDbl` for it (see below for options).

---

[Range.Value2 Property (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-value2-property-excel) article suggests that `Date` and `Currency` types are "special" in that they have an "internal representation" that's in stark contrast with displayed value. Indeed:

- [`Date`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/date-data-type) is internally represented as IEEE 64-bit (8-byte) floating-point numbers where the integer part is the date and fractional part is the time
- [`Currency`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/currency-data-type) is also 8-byte but is treated as a fixed-point number with 4 fractional digits (an integer scaled by 10'000)

Apparently, `Match` compares these internal values for performance reasons. So, we must ensure that they, rather than the readable representations, match exactly.

Since `Date` is already floating-point internally, `CDbl(date)` doesn't actually change the data.

For the `Currency` type, `CDbl` does change data, so it's out of question. So either

- use the exact representation of the key (to 4 fractional digits) this way or another if you require exact match, or
- [make the cells in the range actually be formulas with `Round`](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/595743-excel-match-not-working-currency.html)) if the value to compare with comes from elsewhere and/or you only require equality to 2 fractional digits

Answer (score 1):

This way it works using this method:

`Nbr,L, C` as Integer

`Datedeb` as date

```
nbr = WorksheetFunction.Match(CLng(CDate(Datedeb)), Range(Cells(L, C), Cells(L + 100, C)), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I can safely assume that the value in F1 is a date. In you code "Sep 2008" is a string. You will never be able to get a successful match as long as your datatypes are inconsistent.
If you are looking for a date, then make sure that the first parameter is a date.

```
Dim dSearchSDate As Date

dSearchSDate = "01/Sept/2008"

x = Application.Match(dSearchSDate, Range("F1:F1"), 0)
```

Here is another possible approach.

```
Sub temp()
Dim x
Dim dSearchSDate As Date

    dSearchSDate = "01/Sept/2008"

    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("F1:F1").Value = dSearchSDate Then
        Debug.Print "Found it!"
    Else
        Debug.Print "Doh!!"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to achieve? Match may not be the right approach at all.

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is old, but I had the same issue, and did find the answer.

To make it work, you first need to make VBA see the same data formatting as it appears in your excel spreadsheet :

YourVar  = Format("YourDate","mmm-yyyy")
YourResult = Application.match(Clng(Cdate(YourVar)), YourRange, 0)

Regards

Gilles