# Worksheetfunction.countifs - doesn't recognise dates?

Tags: vba, excel, worksheet-function, countif

As part of a larger project I'm trying to get a count of the instances of dates between a search range.

So for example my date range is `02/01/2014` to `04/01/2014` and in my search range the date `02/01/2014` appears 4 times, `03/01/2014` appears 3 times and `04/01/2014` appears 3 times then the count would return a value of 10.

I can get this to work with numbers - so similarly assuming my search range is 2 to 4 and in my search range 2 appears 4 times, 3 appears 3 times and 4 appears 3 times then the count does return 10. But when I do exactly the same with dates then the count returns 0.

So here's the 2 test codes - I have numbers in column A and dates in column B

```
Sub testnumbers()
Dim Val As Double
    Val = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("A:A"), ">=2", Range("A:A"), "<=4")
MsgBox Val

End Sub
```

Returns the correct count in `Val`. While

```
Sub testdates()
Dim Val As Double
    Val = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("B:B"), ">=02/01/2014", Range("B:B"), "<=04/01/2014")
MsgBox Val

End Sub
```

returns a value of 0 to `Val` as if it hasn't found any instances of any dates in the range.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? It just doesn't seem to see the dates properly...

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Also, these work in Excel outside VBA without any issue. Only in VBA does the date one return a 0...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel VBA Countif between dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644714/excel-vba-countif-between-dates)

Comment: The suggested duplicate has the real solution. You were probably just lucky in that the internal representation of something happened to be in range.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub testdates()
    Dim Val As Double, wf As WorksheetFunction, r As Range, _
        d1 As Date, d2 As Date

    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    Set r = Range("B:B")
    d1 = DateValue("2/1/2014")
    d2 = DateValue("4/1/2014")

    Val = wf.CountIfs(r, ">=" & d1, r, "<=" & d2)
    MsgBox Val
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Still no joy on that one I'm afraid... I still get a 0 returned to the Val variable :(

Comment: Cracked it (through trying random stuff more than anything).. the date variables (d1 and d2 in your example) have to be set between #. So it would be 'd1 = #2/1/2014#' and that for some reason allows VBA to compare the date variables to the dates in the list.

Comment: @HarleyB Perhaps the **#** forces a conversion to *Date*